# Multiple meshes with the same atomic index, Export will be invalid?

Tags: modeling, error, file-format

Im using the dragonff addon for blender 2.8 and i keep getting this error while trying to import multiple .dff files (it succesfully imports around 200 files than gives me the error)

and i don't know if its the addon that's the problem or what "atomic index" even is

#refrence: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tfIO.jpg

so if anyone can help i'd apprechiate that

thanks

Comment: Looks like you have a bad dff file and the importer isn't handling it well. You might want to check GTO forums where you might have more luck finding an answer

Comment: have you tried just importing the 200th file?  I.e. try to see if there is one particular file that is bad as Marty says?